# add dataframe to another one

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'd like to make a summary of a `dataframe`. I got some outputs. I would like to combine the three `dataframe` into a `dataframe` that will be exactly like the first one.

Here is what I did.

```
// Compute column summary statistics.
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val dataframe = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/donnee/cassandraTest_1.csv")
val colNames=dataframe.columns
val data=dataframe.describe().show()

+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|summary|               Col0|               Col1|               Col2|               Col3|               Col4|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  count|               9999|               9999|               9999|               9999|               9999|
|   mean| 0.4976937166129511| 0.5032998128645433| 0.5002933978916888| 0.5008783202471074|0.49977372871783293|
| stddev| 0.2893201326892155|0.28767789122296994|0.29041197844235034|0.28989958496291496| 0.2881033430504947|
|    min|4.92436811557243E-6|3.20277176946531E-5|1.41602940923349E-5|6.53252937203857E-5| 5.4864212896146E-5|
|    max|  0.999442967120299|    0.9999608020298|  0.999968873336897|  0.999836584087385|  0.999822016805327|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
println("Skewness")
val Skewness = dataframe.columns.map(c => skewness(c).as(c))
val Skewness_ = dataframe.agg(Skewness.head, Skewness.tail: _*).show()
```

Skewness

```
   +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |                Col0|                Col1|                Col2|                Col3|                Col4|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |0.015599787007160271|-0.00740111491496...|0.006096695102089171|0.003614431405637598|0.007869663345343194|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    println("Kurtosis")
    val Kurtosis = dataframe.columns.map(c => kurtosis(c).as(c))
    val Kurtosis_ = dataframe.agg(Kurtosis.head, Kurtosis.tail: _*).show//kurtosis
Kurtosis
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|               Col0|               Col1|               Col2|               Col3|              Col4|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|-1.2187774053075133|-1.1861812968784207|-1.2107252263053805|-1.2108988817869097|-1.199054929668751|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I would like to add to skewness and the kurtosis `dataframe` to the first one and add their names into the first colummns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I misread your question and posted a wrong answer, sorry. Deleted, I'll see if I can come up with a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `summary` column to both `skewness` and `kurtosis` tables using `withColumn`

```
val Skewness_ = dataframe.agg(Skewness.head, Skewness.tail: _*).withColumn("summary", lit("Skewness"))
```

Do the same for kurtosis

```
val Kurtosis_ = dataframe.agg(Kurtosis.head, Kurtosis.tail: _*).withColumn("summary", lit("Kurtosis"))
```

Use `Select` in all `dataframes` to have the `column` names in order

```
val orderColumn = Vector("summary", "col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
val Skewness_ordered = Skewness_.select(orderColumn.map(col):_*)
val Kurtosis_ordered = Kurtosis_.select(orderColumn.map(col):_*)
```

and `union` them.

```
val combined = dataframe.union(Skewness_ordered).union(Kurtosis_ordered)
```

Comment: it took to much time especially when dealing with huge dataset , is there a way to make it faster ? Many thanks

Comment: I guess thats the way I know of. :)

Answer (score 0):

In elegant way you can combine your dataframes Skewness and Kurtosis with initial one to new dataframe as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val result = dataframe.union(Skewness.select(lit("Skewness"),Skewness.col("*")))
      .union(Kurtosis.select(lit("Kurtosis"),Kurtosis.col("*")))

result.show()
```